# How to install JDeveloper 12.2.1.3 on a M1 Macbook?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Any hints how to install `jdev 12.2.1.3 or 12.2.1.4` on a laptop with a new `M1 chip`?

I installed `jdk8` from Zulu, started the `jdev` installed:

```
kresimirzic@Kresimirs-MacBook-Pro jdev % java -jar jdev_suite_122130.jar
Launcher log file is /private/var/folders/wt/39zw_r0s7r1b7fcsqc9c63sc0000gn/T/OraInstall2023-03-26_09-42-52PM/launcher2023-03-26_09-42-52PM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . . . . Done
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inventory.InventoryUtils.getDefaultInvPtrLoc(InventoryUtils.java:121)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.PlatformHelper.getDefaultInventoryPointerFile(PlatformHelper.java:492)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Utils.getInvPtrLoc(Utils.java:435)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.doMainHelper(Launcher.java:2276)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:4075)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:3938)
kresimirzic@Kresimirs-MacBook-Pro jdev %
```

But no success. Installation with root user is not allowed as well.

Thx Kresimir

Comment: First verify that you're running a 1.8 vm - `java -version`, because it gets significantly further than the error (which indicates oracle jdk, but not java 8). if you're not running the jdk 1.8, then you can use `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 -e java -jar jdev_suite_122130.jar`.

Comment: thx, I did. I am running java 1.8 :-)

Comment: I don't know what to say - it works on my machine, with the oracle 1.8 jdk. When I attempt to use zulu, it says 'nope, this is openjdk'. You haven't given the output of `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` which would list all the JDKs that are installed, which might give you a pointer to a potential issue

Comment: Thx, how did you start the Oracle installer? Any particular permissions required for the file system?

Comment: kresimirzic@Kresimirs-MacBook-Pro jdev % /usr/libexec/java_home -V      
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.0_362 (arm64) "Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 8.68.0.21" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
kresimirzic@Kresimirs-MacBook-Pro jdev %